# How to make multiple outputs on logstash?

Tags: logstash

I want to sent to multiple destinations on logstash, here it is my configuration:

```
output {
   elasticsearch {
    hosts => "10.10.10.7:9200"
    index => "ubuntu18"
  }

   kafka {
      bootstrap_server => "10.10.10.6:9092"                                                                
      codec => json                                                                                        
      topic_id => "beats" 
 }
}
```

But it is not working, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your kafka output configuration is wrong, it is `bootstrap_servers` not `bootstrap_server`.

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "10.10.10.7:9200"
        index => "ubuntu18"
    }
    kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => "10.10.10.6:9092"                                                                
        codec => json                                                                                        
        topic_id => "beats" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes OMG! I dont see , It's done thank u @leandrojmp